# Can Mahapps MetroWindow Template Be Overridden?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I want to create a notification window using `Mahapps.Metro`. I defined a new `Style` for `MetroWindow` but when `Show()` is executed, application throws a null exception. If i remove the template override, i have no problem... Any ideas?

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:ctrl="clr-namespace:MyApp.Controls"
                    xmlns:Controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls">
<Style x:Key="ErrorPopup" TargetType="{x:Type Controls:MetroWindow}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Controls:MetroWindow}}">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ErrorPopupBorderBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="100"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="300"/>
        <Setter Property="ResizeMode" Value="NoResize"/>
        <Setter Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Controls:MetroWindow}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3">
                            <Rectangle.Fill>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="Red"/>
                            </Rectangle.Fill>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="X" Padding="0,0,0,0"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="Error Title" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                        <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>


<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="MyApp.Controls.NotificationPopup"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        xmlns:Controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
        Style="{StaticResource ErrorPopup}" ButtonBase.Click="Button_Clicked" Title="Notification Title">
    <Controls:MetroWindow.Content>
        <TextBlock x:Name="_textContainer" Style="{StaticResource NotificationText}" Text="This is the text to display" TextAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    </Controls:MetroWindow.Content>    
</Controls:MetroWindow>
```

Comment: Well, you mangled the control's template.... and that causes a `System.NullReferenceException` at `\MahApps.Metro-master\MahApps.Metro-master\MahApps.Metro\Controls\MetroWindow.cs:line 887`. Perhaps the better question to ask here is why VS can't generate a workable `Style` and/or `Template` for `MetroWindow` either. Perhaps it was meant this way... Apparently this is not in their **Issues** list on _GitHub_, based on a quick inspection.